# Choose where to save a file in android

Tags: java, android

I have an object("jsonized" to a string) and I want to save it in a file.
Also, I want that a dialogbox shows up allowing the user to pick up the folder where the file will be saved.
(I was writing this question when, suddenly, the solution hit me. Just sharing my solution to get feedback of better ways to do this)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving already working code. You may be able to get help on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the "Save File" button is clicked, it launches "selectFolder()" function

Activity.java

```
    public void selectFolder(){

    // Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
    builder.setTitle("Choose folder to save profile");

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_selectfolder, null);

    ListView lvDirectories = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.lvDirectories);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    ((TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvJamesBond)).setText(path);

    final ArrayList<String> items = listFolders(path);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);


    lvDirectories.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String dest = ((ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.lvDirectories)).getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim();
            String path;
            if(dest.compareTo("...")==0){
                int lastSlash = ((TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvJamesBond)).getText().toString().lastIndexOf("/");
                path =  ((TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvJamesBond)).getText().toString().substring(0,lastSlash);
            }
            else{
                path = ((TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvJamesBond)).getText().toString() + "/" + dest;
            }
            items.clear();
            items.addAll(listFolders(path));
            ((TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvJamesBond)).setText(path);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    lvDirectories.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    // Add the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            saveProfile(((TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvJamesBond)).getText().toString());
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    // Get the AlertDialog from create()
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}

public ArrayList<String> listFolders(String path){
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(path);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    Log.d("TEST PATH1", path);
    Log.d("TEST PATH1", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
    if(path.compareTo(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString())!=0){
        result.add("...");
    }
    for (File inFile : files) {
        if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
            result.add(inFile.getName());
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public void saveProfile(String folder){

    String fileName = "default.txt";

    try{
        String ob = new Gson().toJson(((MyApplication)getApplication()).getProfile());
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(folder+"/"+fileName));
        outputStreamWriter.write(ob);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        Log.e("SAVE_FILE", ex.toString());
    }

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile saved to file '"+fileName+"'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

}
```

dialog_selectfolder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvDirectories"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvJamesBond"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```